# SaveAs in VBA saving in folder above not the same folder

Tags: excel, vba, helper

```
Sub Log_SaveAs()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Copy
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  With wb
    .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Log.xlsx"
    .Close False
  End With
End Sub
```

''''
It currently saves in the folder above this one rather then the same! any help would be great
''''

Comment: Your code should save in the folder where the workbook keeping the code is. If you want saving in the `ActiveWorkbook` folder, you should state this and I will show you what modification should be made... In fact, If this is the case, you should  change `ThisWorkbook.Path` with `ActiveWorkbook.Path`.

Comment: Still alive? Can you clarify what is it about?

Comment: hi @FaneDuru this solution unfortunately did not work, it saved it in a location that I was unable to find. [thisworkbook.path] still seems to be the best option even though it is saving it in the file above the one this document is in

e.g., file path a > b > c

The doc this is saved in is in c but when the new sheets are created and saved from this file they end in b, hope this clarifies

It is being used in a way of backup, when macros are run it changes data in these worksheets. I am giving the user an option to save a copy of them before any changes are made